# I have to print some values from the nested arrays i tried with foreach syntax but somehow i'm not doing it right

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have to print some values from the nested arrays i tried with foreach syntax but somehow i'm not doing it right .

So this is the code :

```
    <?php

    echo "<strong><h1>EXERCISES</h1></strong>";

    /*THree friends (John Doe , Jane Foo , and Elvis Peanutbutter ) 
    are playing the 6/49 lottery and each selects 6 numbers on their
    lottery tickets. */

    /* 1. Define a nested a array to hold their first
    name; last name and the ticket with 6 numbers.*/

    $friends = array();
    $friends[1] = array('first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe', 'ticket' => array(1,3,21,4,54,32));
    $friends[2] = array('first_name'=>'Jane', 'last_name'=>'Foo','ticket' => array(31,13,12,14,45,43));
    $friends[3] = array('first_name'=>'Elvis', 'last_name'=>'Peanutbutter','ticket' => array(33,11,12,24,44,54));

    /* 2. Elvis selects a 7th number ,  add it to his 
       ticket*/

    $friends[3]['ticket'][6] = 5 ;

    /* 3. Jane cancels her ticket, so remove her
     numbers array completly*/

     unset($friends[2]['ticket']) ;

     /* 4. For each friend, display their first name and 
     the number of numbers they have on the ticket*/

    foreach ( $friends as $friend ) {
    echo $friend['first_name'] . ' has ';

    if ( isset( $friend['ticket'] ) ) {
       echo count($friend['ticket']);
    } 
    else {
        'NO';
    }
    echo ' tickets<br>';
}
    ?>
```

Now that error don't show up but the nr of the tickets don't show up either .

Comment: Just paste the code and add 4 blank spaces in front of each line. Or paste the code, highlight the code, press CTRL+K and it will indent the code for you automatically

Comment: You will need to loop through the array with a foreach() -- foreach ($friends as $friend) and dump the $friend variabele to check what's in it.

Comment: Thank you for the posting advice but there i need  a more complexe syntax  for that exercise . if i put :                                                           foreach ($friends as $friend ) {
echo $friend;
}        i do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreach should do it, but you have to remember that each item delivered by the foreach, is in fact an array also.

```
<?php

echo "<strong><h1>EXERCISES</h1></strong>";

/*THree friends (John Doe , Jane Foo , and Elvis Peanutbutter )
are playing the 6/49 lottery and each selects 6 numbers on their
lottery tickets. */

/* 1. Define a nested a array to hold their first
name; last name and the ticket with 6 numbers.*/

$friends = array();
$friends[1] = array('first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe', 'ticket' => array(1,3,21,4,54,32));
$friends[2] = array('first_name'=>'Jane', 'last_name'=>'Foo','ticket' => array(31,13,12,14,45,43));
$friends[3] = array('first_name'=>'Elvis', 'last_name'=>'Peanutbutter','ticket' => array(33,11,12,24,44,54));

/* 2. Elvis selects a 7th number ,  add it to his
   ticket*/

$friends[3]['ticket'][6] = 5 ;

/* 3. Jane cancels her ticket, so remove her
 numbers array completly*/

 unset($friends[2]['ticket']) ;

 /* 4. For each friend, display their first name and
 the number of numbers they have on the ticket*/

foreach ( $friends as $friend ) {
    echo $friend['first_name'] . ' has ';

    if ( isset( $friend['ticket'] ) ) {
        echo count($friend['ticket']);
    } else {
        echo 'NO';
    }
    echo ' tickets<br>';
}
```

Produces the output

```
John has 6 tickets
Jane has NO tickets
Elvis has 7 tickets
```

Comment: so that it's working thanks  , this is the result :                                                                                                                            EXERCISES

John has 6 tickets

Notice: Undefined index: ticket in C:\xampp\htdocs\fasttrackit_php2\Homework\course_4.php on line 31
Jane has 0 tickets
Elvis has 7 tickets

Comment: Ah yes, Exercise 3, you deleted Janes `ticket` array but not Jane. One moment I'll add a test

Comment: o changed that    unset($friends[2]['ticket']) ;

Comment: but still   the error shoes up :                                                                                                                   Notice: Undefined index: ticket in C:\xampp\htdocs\fasttrackit_php2\FavianIoel\Homework\course_4.php on line 32

Comment: Post your actual code, as I suggested in my first comment as it would help to know what line 32 actually is

Comment: Just added a couple of echo's that I missed ealier as well

Comment: Added the full code, and the output generated. TESTED

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($friends as $friend){
  echo $friend['first_name'];
    foreach($friend['ticket'] as $num){
      echo $num;
    }
}
```

I have not tried it. Please try it and post back your results.